# How to exclude non English phrase or word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regular expression to select words/phrases 
[\w*]

- Make dim
- headword
- distinctness
- 暗淡的,
- @denotation="
- "us"=>["

From the above examples. What I need to the first three words.

What kind of REGEX could fix the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact requirements? Do you mean you have input strings like above and you need to make sure your regex identifies the first three items (`Make dim`, `headword` and `distinctness`) as valid?

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://regex101.com/r/7wTM3M/1/

Comment: What regex have you tried?  What specific issue are you struggling with?    http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: What defines "an english word"? For example "[résumé](https://painintheenglish.com/case/193/)" has been adopted into english even though english doesn't (generally) use accents. So do you include `é` in your regex? If you do, you also allow wéird illegal uses; if you don't you exclude some valid english. Aside from that, the suggested solutions would accept _"uquizenfri"_ which is clearly not english. The fact is - you can't use a regex to determine whether or not a word is english, you need a dictionary of the english language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
^[A-Za-z ]+$
```

A single character in the range between A-Z or a-z (case sensitive).

`^` and `$` match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: `^[A-Za-z ]+$` will also validate a space only string.

Comment: Yes, multiple words in a phrase also.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain what Wiktor is telling you is that you should match both separately such that you use `[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*` otherwise the OP may get unwanted results

Comment: OP haven't provided the exact requirements.